# How to handle 'TimeoutException'? pageLoadTimeout is not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

**Scenario**: Need to download a file from website.

**What is happening?**

- On clicking the download button, the page is loading for more than 6 to 7 minutes (This is an application issue). After that, download is getting started.
- As selenium default `pageLoadTimeout` is 300 seconds. It is throwing the below error after 5 minutes.

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving
> message from renderer: 300.000

**What I need to handle?**

As this is the application issue, I don't want to wait till the default time out gets completed. i.e. I want to throw error if page is not loaded within given time.

**What I did?**

```
public boolean clickElement(WebElement element, int timeOut, String message) {
    try {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        element.click();
        return true;
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e1) {
        Reports.logFail(message);
    } finally {
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using `pageLoadTimeout` method to change the default time and once my work is done setting back the `pageLoadTimeout` to 300 seconds (default).

**Issue**: After performing `element.click();` WebDriver is not waiting for give time, it is immediately returning `true` even though page is not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `element.click()` just does a click. So it is not blocked by further page load. Rather next action would wait until page has loaded (since the next action need to have DOM built, etc.)

So I would try to add some waiter (or even better an action) after the click and before return. So that the operation would need to have the page loaded and timeout would probably work for you in that case.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey,  on performing `element.click()` no DOM changes are happening that is why it is immediately skipping the time out. But when I didn't use `pageLoadTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` then  `element.click()` is being kept on hold for 5 minutes.